# Google Cloud Vertex AI with .Net

Tags: .net, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, nlp, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am new to google cloud service VERTEX AI.

I am looking to Create, train, and deploy an AutoML text classification model through .Net application. I did not find anything for .Net with Vertex AI. If someone can please guide my to the location or any .Net code samples, will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1/latest) NuGet package for .NET. Additionally, check the [Github of Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/tree/main/apis/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1) NuGet Package where you can see the sample codes.

Comment: Can this package be used to create video action recognition batch predictions?
I.e. is it the same as other client libraries?

Comment: AutoML isn't Vertex AI - they're different ML products.

Answer (score 3):

The .NET library for Vertex AI is [Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1) ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/latest)).

We don't have samples for .NET I'm afraid, but I expect that if you follow through the Java samples, you can adapt them easily for .NET.

Comment: Can I get a batch prediction for video action recognition as in other libraries?
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/video-data/action-recognition/get-predictions

Comment: @MrPatience: I would assume so, given that the other libraries are just making RPCs as well. The Java example should be relatively straightforward to translate into C#.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi, can we make requests to VertexAI Generative AI Language model 'text-bison' with this library on .NET? Thanks

Comment: @fatihyildizhan: I don't know, I'm afraid. Anything that can be done from the *published* protos in https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis should be doable from the .NET client, but I don't know details about that API, and there may be some aspects that aren't published in the protos yet.